# Uploading an image to server using CakePHP 1.3

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload, cakephp-1.3, dropzone.js

I'm currently stuck implementing image upload using CakePHP 1.3.

I am using the [dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#server-side-implementation) library to handle upload and post request for the server, the documentation for this library states the following:

> **Server side implementation**
>
> Dropzone does not provide the server side implementation of handling the files, but the way files are uploaded is identical to simple file upload forms like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" />
</form>
```

I found some image upload code which looks like it would work, however **I don't know how I can retrieve the post request using CakePHP 1.3.**

**Information about my setup**

The image upload is located on the view: `banners\admin_index.ctp`
The website URL for this location is: `site.com/admin/banners/`

I have a controller called `banners_controller.ctp` which has the following functions:

- `admin_index()`   -- Which renders the view
- `add()` -- This uses `$this->data` to save the files using `uploadFile()`
- `uploadFile()` -- This uploads the file onto the server

Currently the `add()` and `uploadFile()` functions are not being used. I need to figure out how to handle the post request and direct it to these functions.

A full version of my code can be located [here](http://pastebin.com/3ZwZ2VXJ)

In my view, I am creating the forms which dropzone.js links to like so:

```
<form action="add" class="dropzone" id="adropzone"></form>
```

When the form action is set to `add`, it gives the response 'Server responded with 0 code.', when I look in the Chrome network tab, there is a request to 'admin/banners/add' and says `(failed) net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`. When I visit this page manually, I get a redirect loop: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

I am not very familiar with CakePHP 1.3 at all, however I am required to add this to the site, any help or links to external resources would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Whatever you know about uploading files with PHP applies in principle to CakePHP. You seem to already have a working solution - what part of what you are doing is a problem? If you submit your form to `banners/uploadFile` for example, you're going to hit the function `uploadFile`. <- You probably don't want that to happen btw.

Comment: I generally have relatively little knowledge on PHP. The problem is that I am unsure how the framework directs the requests, and how I can then use them, ideally I would like the request to be sent to the add() function. I am using a form with the action of `'/file-upload'`, does this mean that I need the function name needs to be **file-upload** ?

Comment: That's related to [routes](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Configuration.html#routes-configuration), you can't name a function `file-upload` as that's a parse error but yes that's how the standard routes work. If you're very new to CakePHP  [do the blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Tutorials-Examples.html) before continuing - also note that 1.3 is not the current version, so you're starting with something which is old/obsolete.

Comment: I tried changing the action to `/add` which is the same as the function name for the image request, however this hasn't fixed anything unfortunately. 

And yes, I understand that Cake 1.3 is obsolete- however I am doing this as work for a company, so it's an old platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ with CakePHP file Upload plugin